# Electron with Angular app file structure

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron

What's the best practice of creating an Electron app with Angular as UI framework?

My current proposal (which i think is not the best):

- (root)
- ---- node_modules/
- ---- package.json
- ---- index.js
- ---- app/
- ---- ---- node_modules
- ---- ---- package.json
- ---- ---- bower.json
- ---- ---- bower_components/
- ---- ---- backend/ # contains all core logic as node modules
- ---- ---- ui/ # angular application code
- ---- ---- ---- controllers
- ---- ---- ---- services
- ---- ---- ---- templates

Now, i have the backend encapsulates the core logic and exposes some APIs, which i include (require) from ui/services and wrap it as Angular service and then inject/use in controllers normally.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say it's the best, but here's what I normally use:

```
┌ .
├ app/
├── dist/
├──── css/
├──── fonts/
├──── js/
├── src/
├──── css/
├──── js/
├── index.html
├ bower.json
├ bower_components/
├ index.js
├ gulpfile.js
├ node_modules/
└ package.json
```

So, `./index.js` is the entry point. It basically loads `./app/index.html` and inside that file, I refer the files under `./app/dist` folder. `./app/src` is where I do my code changes. And `./gulpfile.js` is simply a tasklist such as converting SASS files to css (from `./app/src/css` to `./app/dist/css`), bundling, minification, linting, etc.

I know, that's not the best structure but by this way I can only type `npm install` and I can get a working environment within the seconds (thanks to postinstall script). It also make easier to manage dependencies on both end. It's up to you how you continue to write your JavaScript and CSS after `./app/src/`, but in the end, they'll be in one file and moved to `./app/dist/`.